# ARM USB functions take too long to excecute

Tags: arm, usb, execution-time

I just started working on a [XMC4500 microcontroller](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/microcontroller/32-bit-industrial-microcontroller-based-on-arm-registered-cortex-registered-m/32-bit-xmc4000-industrial-microcontroller-arm-registered-cortex-registered-m4/channel.html?channel=db3a30433580b3710135a03abaf9385e). I'm currently implementing USB CDC communication and I ran into a problem.
After calling a function "USBD_VCOM_SendData" the program then waits for a frame to send the data. 
More accurately the program waits in the "usbd_endpoint_stream_xmc4000.c" file in the "Endpoint_Write_Stream_LE". There it waits for the endpoint to be ready in the "Endpoint_WaitUntilReady()" function.

```
#define USB_STREAM_TIMEOUT_MS 100


uint8_t Endpoint_WaitUntilReady(void)
{
#if (USB_STREAM_TIMEOUT_MS < 0xFF)
    uint8_t  TimeoutMSRem = USB_STREAM_TIMEOUT_MS;
#else
    uint16_t TimeoutMSRem = USB_STREAM_TIMEOUT_MS;
#endif

uint16_t PreviousFrameNumber = USB_Device_GetFrameNumber();

    for (;;)
    {
        if (Endpoint_GetEndpointDirection() == ENDPOINT_DIR_IN)
        {
            if (Endpoint_IsINReady())
            {
              return ENDPOINT_READYWAIT_NoError;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (Endpoint_IsOUTReceived())
            {
              return ENDPOINT_READYWAIT_NoError;
            }
        }

        uint8_t USB_DeviceState_LCL = USB_DeviceState;

        if (USB_DeviceState_LCL == DEVICE_STATE_Unattached)
        {
          return ENDPOINT_READYWAIT_DeviceDisconnected;
        }
        else if (USB_DeviceState_LCL == DEVICE_STATE_Suspended)
        {
          return ENDPOINT_READYWAIT_BusSuspended;
        }
        else if (Endpoint_IsStalled())
        {
          return ENDPOINT_READYWAIT_EndpointStalled;
        }

        uint16_t CurrentFrameNumber = USB_Device_GetFrameNumber();

        if (CurrentFrameNumber != PreviousFrameNumber)
        {
            PreviousFrameNumber = CurrentFrameNumber;

            if (!(TimeoutMSRem--))
            {
              return ENDPOINT_READYWAIT_Timeout;
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

This wait time is approximately 100-150us and is to long. When I was working on STM32 microcontrollers the execution time was significantly smaller.

Has anybody delt with this problem before?
Is there a way to write the data to a buffer and then let the peripheral take care of the transaction without the need for processor time?
Or at least trigger an interrupt when the endpoint is ready for the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

The loop terminates instantly if `Endpoint_IsINReady()` returns true.  Perhaps you should try to run that macro in your code, and only send messages to the USB host if it evaluates to true.

Also, to ensure that the library does not use its blocking behavior, you'll have to think about how much data the endpoint buffers can hold at once, and make sure you don't send any more than that at a time.  (You can make your own buffer and send it to the USB library piecemeal if you need to.)